# Parse substring from text

Tags: excel, vba, ldap, substring

I am writing a macro that converts a list of names that are in an LDAP format to First, Last (region).

For those who do not know what LDAP looks like, it is below:

> CN=John Smith (region),OU=Legal,DC=example,DC=comand

In Excel VBA, I do not appear to be able to use string.substring(start, end). A search on Google seems to reveal that Mid(string, start, end) is the best option.

The problem is this: In Mid, the integer for end is the distance from start, not the actual index location of the character. This means that different name sizes will have different ending locations and I cannot use index of ")" to find the end of the region.  Since all of the names start with CN=, I can find the end of the first substring properly, but I cannot find ")" properly because names are different lengths.

I have some code below:

```
mgrSub1 = Mid(mgrVal, InStr(1, mgrVal, "=") + 1, InStr(1, mgrVal, "\") - 4)
mgrSub2 = Mid(mgrVal, InStr(1, mgrVal, ","), InStr(1, mgrVal, ")") - 10)
manager = mgrSub1 & mgrSub2
```

Is there a way to use a set end point instead of an end point that is so many values away from the start?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is vba.. no string.substring ;)

this is more like VB 6 (or any one below).. so you are stuck with mid, instr, len (to get the total len of a string).. I think you missed len to get the total of chars in a string? If you need some clarification just post a comment.

edit:

Another quick hack..

```
    Dim t As String
    t = "CN=Smith, John (region),OU=Legal,DC=example,DC=comand"
    Dim s1 As String
    Dim textstart As Integer
    Dim textend As Integer
    textstart = InStr(1, t, "CN=", vbTextCompare) + 3
    textend = InStr(1, t, "(", vbTextCompare)
    s1 = Mid(t, textstart, textend - textstart)
    MsgBox s1
    textstart = InStr(1, t, "(", vbTextCompare) + 1
    textend = InStr(1, t, ")", vbTextCompare)
    s2 = Mid(t, textstart, textend - textstart)
    MsgBox s2
```

Clearly your problem is that since you need a diference for the second parameter, you should always do some math for it...

Comment: The total number of chars in the string won't help me.  I the length can vary on either side of the ")" so I cannot find the index location to stop based on that.

Comment: can you post an example of the output you need? usually you have to code a for loop to accomplish this

Comment: CN=Smith, John (region),OU=Legal,DC=example,DC=comand
should become
Smith, John (region)

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of using math.  That should have been obvious.  Guess it's been a long day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but here is my implementation of (hopefully) what you want:

```
Function GetName(arg As String) As String
    parts = Split(arg, ",")
    For Each p In parts
        kv = Split(p, "=")
        Key = kv(0)
        Value = kv(1)
        If Key = "CN" Then
            commonName = Value
        End If
    Next p
    regIndex = InStr(1, commonName, "(")
    region = Mid(commonName, regIndex, Len(commonName) - regIndex + 1)
    parts = Split(commonName, " ")
    first = parts(0)
    last = parts(1)
    GetName = first & ", " & last & " " & region
End Function


Sub test()
 'Prints "John, Smith (region)"
 Debug.Print GetName("CN=John Smith (region),OU=Legal,DC=example,DC=comand")
End Sub
```

It illustrates the use of `Split` and `Mid` functions.

It is a quick and dirty implementation serving illustrative purposes only. To use it in real code you need to add several checks (e.g. that the `kv` and `parts` collections contain at least two elements).

**UPD:** To cover two possible formats of the CN field, namely `"last\, first (region)"` and `"first last (region)"` and make things a little less messy I would take the regular expressions approach.

```
Function GetName(arg As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "CN=(\w+)\s*?(\\,)?.*?,"
    End With
    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(arg)
    If REMatches.Count < 1 Then
        GetName = ""
        Return
    End If

    cn = REMatches(0).Value
    withComma = (InStr(1, cn, "\,") > 0)
    If withComma Then
        lastIndex = 0
        firstIndex = 2
        regionIndex = 3
        patt = "(\w+)\s*?(\\,)?\s*?(\w+)\s*(\(.*?\))"
    Else
        lastIndex = 1
        firstIndex = 0
        regionIndex = 2
        patt = "(\w+)\s*?(\w+)\s*(\(.*?\))"
    End If
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = patt
    End With
    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(arg)
    If REMatches.Count < 1 Then
        GetName = ""
        Return
    End If

    Set m = REMatches(0)
    first = m.SubMatches(firstIndex)
    last = m.SubMatches(lastIndex)
    region = m.SubMatches(regionIndex)
    GetName = first & ", " & last & " " & region
End Function


Sub test()
 ' Prints "first, last (AAA-somewhere)" two times.
 Debug.Print GetName("CN=last\, first (AAA-somewhere),OU=IT,OU=Users,OU=somewhere - aaa,OU=place,DC=aaa,DC=com")
 Debug.Print GetName("CN=first last (AAA-somewhere),OU=IT,OU=Users,OU=somewhere - aaa,OU=place,DC=aaa,DC=com")
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but when I try GetName(CN=last\, first (AAA-somewhere),OU=IT,OU=Users,OU=somewhere - aaa,OU=place,DC=aaa,DC=com) I get an error subscript out of range at Value = kv(1) on its second time through the loop.

Comment: @spassen, I didn't know there could be commas (escaped) in the name. This will complicate the code.

Comment: I actually figured it out.  I completely forgot I could do end - start.  It's been a long day.  Thanks for the help though.  That's a useful function for future use.

Answer (score 3):

I would use InStr to find the position of the three characters that separate the values and then use Left/Right on them.

This is what I hacked together real quick:

```
Dim tmp, new_string, first, last, region As String

tmp = "CN=John Smith (region),OU=Legal,DC=example,DC=comand"

new_string = Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - 3)
' John Smith (region),OU=Legal,DC=example,DC=comand
new_string = Left(new_string, (InStr(1, new_string, ",") - 2))
' John Smith (region)

region = Right(new_string, Len(new_string) - InStr(1, new_string, "("))
' region
new_string = Left(new_string, (InStr(1, new_string, "(") - 2))
' John Smith

last = Right(new_string, Len(new_string) - InStr(1, new_string, " "))
' Smith
first = Left(new_string, (InStr(1, new_string, " ") - 1))
' John
```

Then concatenate them to get the string output you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first/last name bit is easy if you start with this:

```
MsgBox Split(Mid$(sLDAP, 4), ")")(0) & ")"
```